# How to show number of row in section after tapping on section header in swift?

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a tableView  which contain some

[image]

But i want it to show only section header and when i tap on section header it will show all employee details contining that section only.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return company.count
}



 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return company[section].employees!.count
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if company[section].employees!.count < 1 {

        return nil
    }

    return company[section].companyName
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! EmployeeTableViewCell
    let employeeDetails =  company[indexPath.section].employees!.allObjects as! [Employees]

    cell.lblName.text = employeeDetails[indexPath.row].employeeName
    cell.lblAddress.text = String(employeeDetails[indexPath.row].address!)
    cell.lblAge.text = String(employeeDetails[indexPath.row].age!)

    return cell
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First add a button on your header view on that you can call a function for extending cell .

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let titleHeader =  company[section].companyName // Also set on button
    let  headerCell = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0   , 0, tableView.frame.size.width , 40 ))
    headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let button  = UIButton(frame: headerCell.frame)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "selectedSectionStoredButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
  button.setTitle(titleHeader, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    button.tag = section
    headerCell.addSubview(button)

    return headerCell
    }
```

Now check selected header view on buttonclicked

```
func selectedSectionStoredButtonClicked (sender : UIButton) {
    if (selectedArray.containsObject(sender.tag)){
        selectedArray.removeObject(sender.tag)
    }else{
        //selectedArray.removeAllObjects()  // Uncomment it If you don't want to show other section cell . 
        selectedArray.addObject(sender.tag)
    }
    tableViewObj.reloadData()
}
```

**NOTE :-**  Here I declared **selectedArray** as **NSMutableArray** Global **"tableViewObj"** is your tableview object

Now proceed for final steps . make changes in your **numberOfRowsInSection**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (selectedArray.containsObject(section)){
        return  company[section].employees!.count

    }else{
        return 0
    }
}
```

Try it , It'll work fine , If you have any confusion than leave comment.

Comment: I have declared mySelected array like this:  var selectedArray : NSMutableArray!                                                                                                   and  i am getting a crash when tapping on section header on this line                     if (selectedArray.containsObject(sender.tag)) {

Comment: declare array like this       var selectedArray : NSMutableArray = []

Comment: @S.Bharti  I added one line in selectedSectionStoredButtonClicked check it. If you will uncomment this than other section will hide row

Comment: i have done it but thanks again for your valuable time.

Comment: @Jogendra.Com. I want add rows on tapping tableview header section in swift. How can i achieve this ,please guide me because some other sections are different height .

Answer (score 1):

Create a varialbe like

```
 var hiddenSections: [Int] = []
```

//TableView

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tempContact.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if hiddenSections.contains(section) {
        return 0
    }
    return tempContact[section].count
}
```

//Create a headerCell add label and a button .do it in storyboard

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell")! as! HeaderCell

    header._lblName.text = tempContact[section].NAME
     header._btnExpand.addTarget(self, action: "hideSection:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return header.contentView
}
```

//Button Click

```
func hideSection(sender: UIButton) {
    if hiddenSections.contains(sender.tag) {
        hiddenSections.removeAtIndex(hiddenSections.indexOf(sender.tag)!)
        _tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sender.tag), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        _tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: sender.tag), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        hiddenSections.append(sender.tag)
        _tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sender.tag), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
 }
```